# The current of M5 and M7 of two stage OTA

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-mirror, ota

Let direct current = 100μ,i know the drain current of M3=M4=M6=M1=M2=100μ

My question :

Is the  drain current of M8=50μ ? Oμ ? i think drain current will flow to the gate of M8 dircectly
                  [image]
Is the  drain current of M5=M1+M2=100μ or M5=M8?

Is the  drain current of M7=M5? or M7=M6?

Comment: Why don't you simulate it and find out?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those weird questions you see once and then, the very first words you say are "*Let direct current = 100μ*", so I am assuming that \$I_{DC}=100µA\$. Which flows straight down through \$M_8\$. And then you are asking about what you said, what the current is through \$M_8\$.

Well... If you put \$100µA\$ through \$M_8\$ then... I suppose \$100µA\$ will flow through \$M_8\$.

Remember, those are MOSFET's, **not** BJT's

---

### EDIT

Woaw, I missed the questions under the image, I didn't see them. It's a messy question.

You say early in your question that you *know* that \$M_3=M_4=M_6=M_1=M_2=100μ\$

The \$M_4 = M_3\$ part is not 100% true. It's rather \$M_4 ≤ M_3\$. It will *try* to make a current mirror, but if it can't... then it will be less.

You got **two** cases here. **A** is when \$V_{IN} > V_{IP}\$ and **B** is when \$V_{IN} ≤ V_{IP}\$.

---

In case **A**, \$V_{IN} > V_{IP}\$, this happens:

\$100µA = M_8 = M_5 = M_1 = M_3\$

\$≈0A = M_6 = M_7\$ and \$M_4 = M_2\$ and \$M_2 = 100µA - M_1 → M_2  ≈0A \$

[image]

---

In case **B**, \$V_{IN} ≤ V_{IP}\$, this happens:

\$100µA = M_8 = M_5 = M_7 = M_6\$

\$50µA = M_1 = M_3 = M_2 = M_4\$

[image]

---

[Here is the simulation that you should've made.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0Ai%20160%20160%20160%20304%200%200.00009999999999999999%0Af%20208%20400%20160%20400%200%201.5%200.02%0Aw%20160%20416%20160%20448%200%0Af%20304%20400%20352%20400%200%201.5%200.02%0Af%20256%20320%20304%20320%200%201.5%200.02%0Aw%20352%20384%20352%20336%201%0Aw%20304%20336%20352%20336%200%0Aw%20304%20304%20304%20256%201%0Af%20448%20320%20400%20320%200%201.5%200.02%0Aw%20352%20336%20400%20336%200%0Aw%20400%20304%20400%20256%201%0Af%20352%20208%20304%20208%201%201.5%200.02%0Af%20352%20208%20400%20208%201%201.5%200.02%0Aw%20304%20240%20352%20240%200%0Aw%20352%20240%20352%20208%200%0Aw%20304%20224%20304%20240%200%0Aw%20304%20240%20304%20256%200%0Aw%20400%20256%20400%20224%200%0Aw%20400%20192%20400%20160%200%0Aw%20304%20192%20304%20160%200%0Aw%20160%20160%20304%20160%200%0Aw%20304%20160%20352%20160%200%0Af%20496%20208%20544%20208%201%201.5%200.02%0Aw%20400%20256%20496%20256%200%0Aw%20496%20256%20496%20208%200%0Aw%20400%20160%20544%20160%200%0Aw%20544%20160%20544%20192%200%0Aw%20208%20400%20304%20400%200%0Aw%20208%20400%20208%20368%200%0Aw%20208%20368%20160%20368%200%0Aw%20160%20368%20160%20384%200%0Aw%20160%20448%20352%20448%200%0Aw%20352%20448%20352%20416%200%0Af%20496%20400%20544%20400%200%201.5%200.02%0Aw%20544%20224%20544%20320%201%0Aw%20544%20320%20544%20384%200%0Aw%20544%20320%20624%20320%202%0Ac%20624%20320%20624%20368%200%201e-8%204.996886997924638%0Ag%20624%20368%20624%20384%200%0Aw%20544%20416%20544%20448%201%0Aw%20544%20448%20352%20448%200%0Aw%20304%20400%20304%20432%200%0Aw%20304%20432%20496%20432%200%0Aw%20496%20432%20496%20400%200%0A172%20256%20320%20224%20320%200%206%203.45%205%200%200%200.5%20Voltage%0A172%20448%20320%20480%20320%200%206%203.6%205%200%200%200.5%20Voltage%0Aw%20352%20160%20400%20160%200%0AR%20352%20160%20352%20128%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0AR%20352%20448%20352%20480%200%200%2040%20-5%200%200%200.5%0Ax%20188%20298%20254%20301%204%2024%20Scroll%0Aw%20160%20304%20160%20368%200%0Ax%20444%20302%20510%20305%204%2024%20Scroll%0A) 
I've marked two voltages "Scroll", put your mouse over the voltages and scroll with your mouse to change the voltage and you will see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

These statements are accurate from a current perspective:

1. M5, M7, and M8 all carry the same current because Vgs is the same across all of them.
2. M3 ~= M4 because Vgs is the same as well (PMOS)
3. M3+M4 = M5
4. M6 only equals M7 if you have a capacitive or high-impedance load which may or may not be true.
5. M1 = M3
6. M2 = M4

Your statement that M4 = M6 is where you're going really wrong. Vgs on those two  is in no way correlated. 
The reason all of these statements above are accurate is because a transistor in saturation for the most part only depends on Vgs, mosfets don't consume any gate current, and transistors (or any component) in series have to carry equal current. These 3 factors greatly simplify the analysis of op-amps.

All of that means the following because current can't flow through gates:
I8 = 100uA
I5 = 100uA
I7 = 100uA